# Registers 0-9 policies

Tags: graphics, registers

I recall seeing somewhere that registers 0-9 are to be used locally if they are even and globally if they are odd (or was it the other way around).  Once you use a register globally, no one else can use it safely.  You have essentially claimed that register for your exclusive use, which is what `\newlength`, `\newcount` and `\newsavebox` are for.

If you **have** to use a register globally and don't want to tie one up permanently, I suggest you grab one from `\@freelist` and release it when done.

Comment: What is the question? :-)

Comment: there is no question here also the final suggestion is a bit odd why not use \newcount or whatever. sharing the scratch registers 0-9 was importat in classic tex with only 250 registers but with over 32 thousand in etex it is not a problem

Comment: also it is possible to share global registers 1,3,5,7,9 you just have to ensure other code does not use it between the places it is set and place it is used, which is often easy to arrange.

Comment: Or you just notice that the values got changed for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The policy of using even-numbered scratch registers locally and odd-numbered ones globally was suggested by Knuth himself in the TeXbook.

Here's the part where they are mentioned the first time (page 122):

> Sometimes, however, you want to use a register just for temporary
> storage, and you know that it won't conflict with anybody else's macros.
> Registers `\count255`, `\dimen255`, `\skip255`, `\muskip255`, and
> `\toks255` are
> traditionally kept available for such purposes.  Furthermore, plain TeX
> reserves `\dimen0` to `\dimen9`, `\skip0` to `\skip9`, `\muskip0` to
> `\muskip9`, and `\box0` to `\box9` for “scratchwork”; these registers
> are never allocated by the `\new...` operations.  We have seen that
> `\count0` through `\count9` are special, and `\box255` also turns out to
> be special; so those registers should be avoided unless you know what you
> are doing.

Knuth's more precise on page 346:

> *2. Allocation of registers.* The second major part of the
> `plain.tex` file provides a foundation on which systems of independently
> developed macros can coexist peacefully without interfering in their
> usage of registers. The idea is that macro writers should abide by the
> following ground rules:
>
> (1) Registers numbered 0 to 9 are always free for
> temporary “scratch” use, but their values are always assumed to be
> clobbered whenever any other macro might get into control. (This applies
> to registers like `\dimen0`, `\toks0`, `\skip1`, `\box3`, etc.; but TeX
> has already reserved `\count0` through `\count9` for page number
> identification.)
>
> (2) The registers `\count255`, `\dimen255`, `\skip255`,
> `\muskip255`, and `\toks255` are freely available in the same way.
>
> (3) All assignments to the scratch registers whose numbers are
> 1, 3, 5, 7, and 9 should be `\global`; all assignments to the
> other scratch registers (0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 255) should be non-`\global`.
> (This prevents the phenomenon of “save stack buildup” discussed
> in Chapter 27.)

LaTeX follows the same rules, because the register allocation system is the same as in plain TeX. Well, it used to be, because now LaTeX also uses the extended range of registers, but for the ones up to 255 it's still essentially the same.

Scratch registers are used quite extensively in the LaTeX kernel, particularly box registers. You can see an example of (global) usage of `\box1` in the code for `\bordermatrix`.

There's little problem in using a register globally: the idea is that in such case, nothing that *might* use the same register can appear; typically something like

```
  \setbox\tw@\vbox{\unvcopy\z@\global\setbox\@ne\lastbox}%
```

Here's a possible problem: you might have something that uses `\box1` in the matrix entries. Say you have a complicated symbol to be constructed with box registers and you need global assignments; so long as you *don't* rely on the contents of the box register across usages, you're safe. Otherwise, allocate a new register.

Sometimes it happens that weird output is produced with local registers, because some macro uses the same registers. In such cases, adding a group level usually solves the issue. But LaTeX uses the extended range, with more than 32000 registers available for each type: in case of even small doubts, allocate a new register.