# How to draw a grid of a certain height which is breakable

Tags: page-breaking, exam

I am writing a set of lecture notes for which there should be two versions: one for me with all of the text, and one for the students with certain sections replaced by a grid for them to make their own notes.

To achieve this, I am trying to define a function `\gap` which can enclose some object (paragraph/figure/theorem/etc) of my lecture notes, and when a Boolean `gaps` is off, it does nothing, and when the Boolean is on, it replaces the object with a grid the width of the text and of an appropriate height.

Taking into account the fact that hand writing is bigger than typeset text, the height of the grid should be some scaled up multiple of the object being replaced. I am defining `\heightmultiplier` as that scale factor which I have set to `2.5`.

On the face of it, this is easy to achieve using the `\fillwithgrid` function which can be copied from the exam class `exam.cls`. This function takes a single numerical argument - the height of the grid to be drawn. The problem is that the grid this produces is not breakable and so the result leaves lots of white space in the lecture notes. Therefore, I am trying to adapt that function to create a breakable grid.

The first function I define is `\fillwithgridbreakable` which, like `\fillwithgrid` takes as argument the height of the grid to be drawn. First it compares this height to the amount of space left on the current page `\remainingspace`, which I define to be `\textheight-\pagetotal`. If there is enough space it draws the grid, otherwise it draws as big a grid as it can before calling itself again to draw a grid of whatever size is left:

```
\newcommand{\fillwithgridbreakable}[1]{
    \newlength{\remainingspace}%
    \setlength{\remainingspace}{\textheight-\pagetotal}%
    \ifdim #1>\remainingspace%
    \fillwithgrid{\remainingspace}%
    \fillwithgridbreakable{#1-\remainingspace}%
    \else%
    \fillwithgrid{#1}%
    \fi
}
```

Then I define the function `\gap` which takes some LaTeX code as input. If the Boolean `gaps` is off it jest runs the code, and otherwise, it measures the height `\height` of whatever that code would produce, and then calls `\fillwithgridbreakable` with argument `\heightmultiplier\height`.

```
\newcommand{\gap}[1]{%
     \ifthenelse{\boolean{gaps}}{%
        \newdimen\height
        \setbox0=\vbox{#1}
        \height=\ht0 \advance\height by \dp0
        \fillwithgridbreakable{\heightmultiplier\height}
     }
     {%
        #1
     }
 }
```

My problem is that I get errors saying that `\gap` is missing a number and units treated as 0, and that the grid it draws is not breakable.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{lipsum} 

\newboolean{gaps}
\setboolean{gaps}{true}

\newcommand{\heightmultiplier}{2.5}

\newcommand{\fillwithgridbreakable}[1]{
    \newlength{\remainingspace}%
    \setlength{\remainingspace}{\textheight-\pagetotal}%
    \ifdim #1>\remainingspace%
    \fillwithgrid{\remainingspace}%
    \fillwithgridbreakable{#1-\remainingspace}%
    \else%
    \fillwithgrid{#1}%
    \fi
}

\newcommand{\gap}[1]{%
     \ifthenelse{\boolean{gaps}}{%
        \newdimen\height
        \setbox0=\vbox{#1}
        \height=\ht0 \advance\height by \dp0
        \fillwithgridbreakable{\heightmultiplier\height}
     }
     {%
        #1
     }
 }

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\gap{\lipsum[1-3]}

\end{document}
```

The output of this, at the first page break, looks like this:
[image: Output of MWE showing large whitespace at the bottom of the first page, and the grid drawn only at the start of the second page]
I would be very grateful for any insight into why this doesn't work and what I can do to fix it. I have searched SE for posts on similar topics. That's how I found out how to measure the height of something as I do in the `\gap` function and how to compute `\remainingspace` and use `\ifdim...\else`. But I couldn't find anything that makes breakable environments from scratch.

This is also my first post on this SE, so let me know if there's anything I can do to improve it.

### Solution

Drawing almost entirely on John Kormylo's solution below, I thought I would set out a working solution here with a couple of bugs fixed and more freedom  to adjust things like grid size and colour.

```
\usepackage{xcolor} %to adjust the grid colour
\usepackage{ifthen} %to create the boolean for turning the functionality of \gaps on and off

\newboolean{gaps}
\setboolean{gaps}{true}

\newcommand{\heightmultiplier}{2.5} %how much taller the grid is than the object it is replacing
\newcommand{\mygridsize}{.5cm} %the size of the grid squares
\colorlet{gridcolor}{gray!50} %the colour of the gridlines
\newcommand{\rulewidth}{0.8pt} %the width of the vertical rules

\newsavebox{\row}
\savebox{\row}{\begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
  {\color{gridcolor}\hrule}
  \dimen9=\mygridsize\relax
  \count9=\numexpr \textwidth / \dimen9\relax
  {\color{gridcolor}\rule{\rulewidth}{\dimen9}}%
  \loop\ifnum\count9>1
    \advance\count9 by -1
    \hfill{\color{gridcolor}\rule{\rulewidth}{\dimen9}}%
  \repeat
  {\color{gridcolor}\hrule}
\end{minipage}}

\newcommand{\fillwithgridbreakable}[1]{% #1 = total height
  \setstretch{1} %if setstretch is changed elsewhere in the document, this prevents it from messing with the grid row spacing
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt} %If included inside a list environment, the prevents the paragraph spacing from messing up with the grid row spacing
  \vfill
  \dimen8=#1\relax
  \dimen9=\mygridsize\relax
  \count8=\numexpr \dimen8 / \dimen9\relax
  \loop\ifnum\count8>0
    \advance\count8 by -1
    \noindent\usebox\row\par\vskip-\lineskip
  \repeat}
  
\newcommand{\gap}[1]{% #1 = text to be replaced
     \ifthenelse{\boolean{gaps}}{%
        \setbox0=\vbox{#1}%
        \fillwithgridbreakable{\dimexpr \heightmultiplier\ht0 + \heightmultiplier\dp0}%
     }
     {%
        #1
     }
 }
```

Comment: Nice first question ...

Comment: it should be possible to create a breakable grid by making each "row" a separate paragraph and slightly overlapping the them.

Comment: You should always put `\newlength` in the preamble.  Otherwise, every time you expand `\fillwithgridbreakable` you will use up another dimen register and assign it to `\remainingspace`.

Comment: Thanks @JohnKormylo, that is very useful to know about `\newlength`, I guess the same goes for `\newdem` too. Having separate rows is an interesting idea, but a bit of a bodge I think -  getting the overlap correct would be fiddly, and if you used `\vspace{-?? pt}` you would probably end up with the first now on the new page too high.

Comment: Actually, \vskip and \vspace are ignored at the top of a page.  I'm more worried about the width.  You may need to add `\hspace*{-\csname @totalleftmargin\endcsname}` at the beginning of each line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shows how to create a truly breakable grid (rather than a broken grid).

Registers 0-9 are supposedly free for use with [some exceptions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/685067/registers-0-9-policies),  `\hrule` is a TeX primitive which (a) draws a line, (b) acts like `\par` and (c) ignores `\baselineskip` and `\lineskip`.  `\loop\if... \repeat` does precisely that.  `\repeat` takes the place of `\fi` for the `\if...`.

Note that `\fullwidth` is not breakable.

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newboolean{gaps}
\setboolean{gaps}{true}

\newcommand{\heightmultiplier}{2.5}

\newcommand{\fillwithgridbreakable}[1]% #1 = total height
{\bgroup
  \sbox9{\begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}% one row of grid
    \hrule
    \dimen9=\heightmultiplier\baselineskip\relax
    \count9=\numexpr \textwidth / \dimen9\relax
    \rule{0.4pt}{\dimen9}%
    \loop\ifnum\count9>1
      \advance\count9 by -1
      \hfill\rule{0.4pt}{\dimen9}%
    \repeat
    \hrule
  \end{minipage}}%
  \ht9=\dimexpr \ht9-0.4pt\relax% overlap borders
  \vfill
  \dimen8=#1\relax
  \count8=\numexpr \dimen8 / \ht9\relax
  \loop\ifnum\count8>0
    \advance\count8 by -1
    \noindent\usebox9\hrule height0pt
  \repeat
\egroup}
  
\newcommand{\gap}[1]{% #1 = text to be replaced
     \ifthenelse{\boolean{gaps}}{%
        \setbox0=\vbox{#1}%
        \fillwithgridbreakable{\dimexpr \heightmultiplier\ht0 + \heightmultiplier\dp0}%
     }
     {%
        #1
     }
 }

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\gap{\lipsum[1-3]}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this answer. It's not clear to me how to adjust the grid size because I don't understand your code. Please could you add a little more detail to clarify this?

Comment: I think I've worked it out. The grid size is determined by `\dimen9` in each function, and changing this to `.5cm` (or indeed whatever height/width one may wish), has the desired result

Comment: Used inside list environments, the rows are separated by extra whitespace. To fix this, once can add `\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}` at the start of the definition of `\fillwithgridbreakable`

Comment: I replaced `\par` with `\hrule height0pt`, which also ignores `\lineskip`.

Answer (score 3):

*This is not really an answer to your nice question*, but too long for a comment, and it might be helpful. I suggest to do something conceptually simpler(?): To (ab)use a tabular environment that can split over several pages (longtable? Maybe there is something better available now?). Then you will get almost all for free, in particular the breaks over the page. You will not measure the other alternative and multiply by 2.5, but isn't it easier to say that you want a certain number of grid lines anyways?

I apologize, but I don't know LaTeX well enough, so I don't know how to do the coding for what I suggest there, but below you find a ConTeXt version:

There is not too much to say about it. The first two settings only set the paper size and the width of the text block, not important. Then we define a macro \MyGrid that takes the number of grid lines as an argument. It typesets a table that can split. Inside the macro, the natural table mechanism is set up and used, and there is a loop. The `\samplefile`s are just there to get some text in.

```
\setuppapersize[A5]

\setuplayout
  [width=10cm]

\starttexdefinition MyGrid #1
\startplacefloat
  [table]
  [location={force,nonumber,split}]
  \setupTABLE
    [width=0.5cm,
     height=0.5cm,
     split=yes]
  \bTABLE
    \dorecurse{#1}{\bTR\dorecurse{20}{\bTD\eTD}\eTR}
  \eTABLE
\stopplacefloat
\stoptexdefinition

\starttext
\samplefile{ward}

\MyGrid {10}

\samplefile{knuthmath}

\MyGrid {40}

\samplefile{ward}
\stoptext
```

[image: context result]

Comment: Thanks for your answer and idea. If the input is a figure/block of text/etc, the easiest thing is to find it's height, so knowing how many rows are required isn't  necessarily so easy. That said, it should be a relatively straightforward extra step to implement.