How can I distribute footnotes across more than one page using Paracol?
Hello everyone and Merry Christmas.
I am working on a project using the PARACOL environment, and I have encountered the problem with footnotes, specifically, large footnotes that do not split or distribute across more than one page, often collapsing on the same page.
I tried using \footnotemark and \footnotetext to manually split the footnotes, but it doesn't work well.
At one point, I tried using \usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc} and \usepackage{bigfoot}, but in addition to not solving the problem at all, they misaligned the entire document, so I had to stop using them. However, if both packages are necessary for a solution, I have no problem using them again. Perhaps I didn't use them correctly back then. I'm not closed to the possibility. I am using LuaLaTeX, although it also works with XeLaTeX.
In summary, I need to find a way for large footnotes to be distributed across more than one page, ideally automatically, under the PARACOL environment.
My Code:
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\headsep=12pt
\headheight=15pt
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{paracol}
\globalcounter*
\footnotelayout{m}
\parindent=20pt
\newcounter{columnstate}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\widowpenalty=10000
\clubpenalty=10000
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{makeidx}
\begin{document}\sloppy
    \begin{paracol}{2}% 
      \lipsum[2]\switchcolumn
      x\footnote{\lipsum[5]\lipsum[5]\lipsum[5]\lipsum[5]\lipsum[5]}\lipsum[2]\switchcolumn*
      \lipsum[5]\switchcolumn
      \lipsum[5]\switchcolumn*
      
    \end{paracol} 
\end{document}

Thank you very much in advance for everything.

what's the intention of \mynumber ? it has an \ifnum test but does the same thing whether the test is true or false?

You can find out how much space is left in the column using \pagegoal-\pagetotal but only between paragraphs.  This splits the footnote based on this number.
I removed every package not related to the MWE on genral princibles.  But please use geometry to make all changes to the page margins.
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
%\usepackage{microtype} 
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\pagestyle{fancy}
\geometry{headsep=12pt, headheight=15pt, showframe}% allow geometry to make all settings
%\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{paracol}
\globalcounter*
\footnotelayout{m}
\parindent=20pt
\newcounter{columnstate}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\widowpenalty=10000
\clubpenalty=10000
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{amssymb} 
%\usepackage{amsthm} 
%\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\pcol@@footnotetext}[1]{% #1 = text (number in \@fnmark)
  \setbox0=\vbox{\hsize=\textwidth
  \reset@font\footnotesize
  \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
  \splittopskip\footnotesep
  \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox \floatingpenalty \@MM
  %\hsize\columnwidth 
  \@parboxrestore
  \def\@currentcounter{footnote}%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
    \csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark}%
  \color@begingroup
  \@makefntext{%
    \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
  \par
  \color@endgroup}%
  \ifdim\pagegoal=\maxdimen
    \dimen0=\textheight
  \else
    \setlength{\dimen0}{\dimexpr \pagegoal-\pagetotal}%
  \fi
  \ifdim\dimen0<\ht0
    \setbox2=\vsplit0 to \dimen0
    \insert\footins{\unvbox2}%
    \pagebreak
  \fi
  \insert\footins{\unvbox0}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}\sloppy
    \begin{paracol}{2}% 
      \lipsum[2]\switchcolumn
      x\footnotemark\lipsum[2]\par
      \footnotetext{\lipsum[5]\lipsum[5]\lipsum[5]\lipsum[5]\lipsum[5]}
      \switchcolumn*
      \lipsum[5]\switchcolumn
      \lipsum[5]\switchcolumn*
      
    \end{paracol} 
\end{document}


Thank you very much, it works correctly. I have been testing it, and it only causes me one problem, which is when on a page there is a giant footnote, and on the next page too, then the first footnote is cut, without continuing on the next page, while the second footnote is only shown on that page without being cut to give the space to the first one.
But everything else works fine, Merry Christmas and greetings.

curiously if I change it to \ifdim\dimen1<\ht0 it looks good, the only problem is that in the first page of this footnote appears the cut that should be in the second page, and in the second page there is the paragraph of the footnote that should be in the first page, that would be the first part of the text next to the number.

\dimen1 contains an unknown length, so no telling what will happen.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/685067/registers-0-9-policies?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C128.8823
